# How does java.awt.Color.getColor(String colorName) work?

Tags: java, colors, awt

I'm trying to get colors by name, and I came across [Converting a String to Color in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854043/converting-a-string-to-color-in-java), which suggests using `java.awt.getColor`.

I can't work out what to pass it as a string though. The following

```
System.out.println( java.awt.Color.getColor( "black", Color.red ) );
```

prints out

> java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0]

i.e. it is going with the default color in there.

I've put this in a text box, and tried alternative capitalisations etc. The docs aren't very helpful here. Can anyone suggest what magic strings to put in?

Comment: If you read the question you linked to more carefully, you'll see that Color.getColor is not a suitable choice. The reflection version in that question seems much more appropriate.

Comment: OK - I read it several times, and the answers imply that I can get colors by name using this method, which is much more concise and natural than using reflection. Is it the case that bwawok's answer is wrong, and there aren't system properties set up for the default color set?

Comment: Yes, that is the case.  The answer is wrong.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The non-accepted answer uses `Color.getColor`.  This method reads from system properties which may or may not be present.  You should not use this method.

Instead, you should use the upvoted reflection method to find the static member of the `Color` class.  Either this, or you should import your own color database which maps string names to RGB values.

```
Color color;
try {
    Field field = Color.class.getField("yellow");
    color = (Color)field.get(null);
} catch (Exception e) {
    color = null; // Not defined
}
```

Comment: Hi Eric, You say: "You should not use this method."... But why? I am currently creating a custom ListCellRenderer. And I want it to use the default colors for a selected item. Your suggestions as to not use this method strikes me as weird.

Comment: I see why you're confused.  The non-accepted answer in the question linked by the OP was removed.  Use the method in the accepted answer, for the reasons I state in this answer.