# Want to use array element as attribute but quotes causes an error Java

Tags: java

I'm really stumped by this simple problem I have.

I have an array with a few colors, like:

```
String[] colors = {"BLACK", "YELLOW", "ORANGE"};
```

and I want to use a color from the array like this:

```
setBackground(Color.colors[1]);
```

but I get the error

```
colors cannot be resolved or is not a field.
```

I'm sure there is a simple solution to my problem?

Thanks!

---

Thanks to everyone for their help! I should have put more detail in my question, it was actually to do with buttons in a GUI.
Big thanks to Igor Rodriguez whose answer was right on the mark :)

Comment: use it as setBackground(colors[1]);

Comment: 1) Is `Color` = `java.awt.Color`? 2) What parameter type does `setBackground` take (`java.awt.Color`?)?

Comment: We need more of your code to tell you what the problems are. What is the type of `this`? Where is this array defined? Where and how is `setBackground()` defined? Where and how is Color defined?

Comment: there's no easy wau in java to get an instance of Color by its string name. closest is listed here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772098/how-does-java-awt-color-getcolorstring-colorname-work

Comment: which attribute? Prove that error is caused by the quotes. I do not believe that. It has nothing to do with buttons in GUI. The error is because you do not have the colors attribute in the Color object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array can't be of type String. It must be of type Color:

```
Color[]  colors = new Color[] {Color.BLACK, Color.YELLOW, Color.ORANGE};
setBackground(colors[0]);
```

Comment: Of course an array *can* be of type `String`, but the code you provided is probably what OP wants.

Comment: @Dukeling: I'm not saying that an array of type String cannot be created. I mean he really shouldn't use an String array to do it, because that would complicate the code unnecessarily. :)

Comment: And I'm not saying what you mean is incorrect, just the way you're saying it is slightly off. This may be better: "Assuming `setBackground` takes `Color` as a parameter and `Color` here is `java.awt.Color`, your array *shouldn't* be of type `String`, it *should* be of type `Color` (otherwise things would be unnecessarily complicated)".

Comment: I didn't because that would mess the asker. You're assuming that he knows that there are different types of colors. Most of people only knows java.awt.Color, and that is because is the one used in Swing. You're right, I really did assume that he tries to set the background color of a component and he is trying to use a list of default colors. If the question would been asked in other way, I wouldn't make such assuptions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean `java.awt.Color`, your array `color` is not a field of that class. Use:

```
setBackground(colors[1]);
```

In that case, [you will need valid `Color` objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setBackground%28java.awt.Color%29) rather than `Strings`, you could use:

```
Color[] colors = {Color.BLACK, Color.YELLOW, Color.ORANGE};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the array notation:

```
setBackground(colors[0]);
setBackground(colors[1]);
setBackground(colors[2]);
```

But I think you want something like this:

```
object.setBackground(Color.black);
```

where object is the element you want to change the color.
(Assuming you are using [java.awt.Color](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/class-use/Color.html))