# How to display the color selected in my combo box

Tags: java

So I'm attempting to make a pretty window displaying the color selected from the combo box. But I got the window and combo box made, for some reason my color isn't displayed. Can anyone help me?

Also from what I can tell, my combo box is at the top of my window. I would like to have it shown below the color.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

class Colors extends JFrame implements ItemListener
{
    Choice chooseColor = new Choice();
    Label lblQts = new Label("Choose color you like : ");

    public Colors(String title)
    {
        super(title);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        chooseColor.addItem("red");
        chooseColor.addItem("green");
        chooseColor.addItem("blue");

        add(lblQts);
        add(chooseColor);

        chooseColor.addItemListener(this);
    }   

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
    {   
        String c;
        Color color;
        c = chooseColor.getSelectedItem();
        color=Color.getColor(c);

        setBackground(color);
    }


}


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Colors objColor = new Colors("Color Chooser");
    objColor.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    objColor.setSize(400,400);
    objColor.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: As I suggested in your last posting, you need to add a `Color` object to the combo box and you need to create a custom renderer. You can't just add a String and expect it to magically represent a Color.

Comment: why are using the AWT Choice class instead of Swing JComboBox ?

Comment: Don't mix light and heavy weight components, this just messes with the z-ordering and never ends well

Comment: Because I'm really confused on how to do this.

Comment: What do you mean you are confused??? You where given a link to the Swing tutorial which contained working examples of using a JComboBox. So why would you make up a different component to use??? This is why you have problems. You don't follow the working code in the tutorial.

Comment: I'm confused cause this is a really hard subject to understand. I just started java a couple weeks ago. To be sure you didn't just pick up a book yesterday either...

Comment: So as I said you start with working code and then make changes to do what you want. You don't just make up code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume for a moment that you really should be using the Swing API and not the AWT API (and seen as you're only just learning I think it's a decent assumption to make).

You can do the following...

Basically.  I have `JComboBox` with a custom `ListCellRenderer` and `ActionListener`.

The `ListCellRenderer` renders the items in a fashion I want and the `ActionListener` listeners for changes to the combobox.

When a new item is selected, it will change the background of the combo box based on the selected item.

The concepts demonstrated here are crucial to understanding Swing (and Java in general)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ComboBoxEditor;
import javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestComboBox08 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestComboBox08();
    }

    public TestComboBox08() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            final JComboBox cb = new JComboBox();
            cb.addItem(new SelectableColor("Red", Color.RED));
            cb.addItem(new SelectableColor("Green", Color.GREEN));
            cb.addItem(new SelectableColor("Blue", Color.BLUE));
            cb.setRenderer(new ColorCellRenderer());
            add(cb);
            cb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    Object value = cb.getSelectedItem();
                    if (value instanceof SelectableColor) {
                        cb.setBackground(((SelectableColor)value).getColor());
                    } else {
                        cb.setBackground(null);
                    }
                }
            });
            cb.setSelectedItem(null);
        }

    }

    public class SelectableColor {
        private String name;
        private Color color;

        public SelectableColor(String name, Color color) {
            this.name = name;
            this.color = color;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public Color getColor() {
            return color;
        }

    }

    public class ColorCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
            super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
            if (value instanceof SelectableColor) {
                SelectableColor sc = (SelectableColor) value;
                if (!isSelected) {
                    setBackground(sc.getColor());
                    setOpaque(true);
                }
                setText(sc.getName());
            }
            return this;
        }

    }

}
```

You really should familiarise yourself with [Creating A UI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).  If that is going over your head, start with [Trails](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html) covering the basics

Comment: Wow clearly I'm in over my head on this work. I guess I need to read over some of the sources provided for me. Thanks for all your effort and input on this assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set contentPane's background, not `JFrame` background.
Then, you can't use `Color.getColor` to retrieve your color object for this case. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772098/how-does-java-awt-color-getcolorstring-colorname-work)

This is the working code:

```
import java.awt.Choice;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Colors  extends JFrame implements ItemListener

{
    Choice chooseColor = new Choice();
    Label lblQts = new Label("Choose color you like : ");

    public Colors (String title) {
        super(title);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        chooseColor.addItem("red");
        chooseColor.addItem("green");
        chooseColor.addItem("blue");

        add(lblQts);
        add(chooseColor);

        chooseColor.addItemListener(this);
    }

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        String c;
        Color color;
        c = chooseColor.getSelectedItem();              
        try {
            Field field = Class.forName("java.awt.Color").getField(c);
            color = (Color)field.get(null);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            color = null; // Not defined
        }    
        getContentPane().setBackground(color);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Colors  objColor = new Colors ("Color Chooser");
        objColor.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        objColor.setSize(400, 400);
        objColor.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: Why bother with reflection?  Why not simply map the `String` values to a `Color` with some sort of `Map`?