# How can I set the backgorund color for a JFrame using a JComboBox from another JFrame?

Tags: java, computer-science, jcombobox

Actually, I'm trying to do a "Setting" window for a game and I want to set the background color of another window. I have no idea what to do. Some ideas pls?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display the color selected in my combo box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995375/how-to-display-the-color-selected-in-my-combo-box)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement it in different places. One of the ways is constructor, for example:

```
    public YourClassPanel() {
// to set Look&Feel    
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ControlPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ControlPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ControlPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ControlPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(this);
            this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                    ControlPanel.tgp = null;
                }
            });

            this.setBounds(0, 0, 710, 580);
            this.setTitle("Buffer Allocation Panel");
            this.setPreferredSize(null);
            this.setResizable(false);

    this.setBackground(Color.yellow); //to set Background
    this.setForeground(Color.magenta); // to set Foreground
    this.setOpaque(a!=255); // to set Opaque

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a different color for `JPanel` background from `Properties`.

Comment: I am a beginner in Java

Comment: Could you explain better?