# Color.getColor("Red") returns null

Tags: java

I would like the user to import a string such a "Red" then be able to pass it to the code below.

```
String red = "Red";
Color color = Color.getColor(red);
System.out.println(color);
```

> output:
>   null

How would I get it to output Red. If that is possible.

Comment: Why don't you use `Color.RED`

Comment: Color docs have red as either all caps or all lower case, maybe you need to use all uppercase

Comment: Because I would like the user to be able to enter a color of their choice such as Red

Comment: *"How would I get it to output Red."* Not to troll you but to output this, simply do `System.out.println("Red");`. I think we all understand what you are trying to do but your question is actually ambiguous the way it's written.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the JavaDoc what [Color.getColor()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#getColor%28java.lang.String%29) says:

> Finds a color in the system properties. 
>   The argument is treated as the name of a system property to be obtained. The string value of this property is then interpreted as an integer which is then converted to a Color object.
>
> If the specified property is not found or could not be parsed as an integer then null is returned.

```
Parameters:
nm - the name of the color property 
Returns:
the Color converted from the system property.
```

**"Red" is not defined as system property.**

Comment: Okay, I obviously made a mistake with this question, my plan is to ask the user for a colour, (Just basic red, blue, yellow etc ) I then need to store that color in a Text file. If I save it as java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0], is their a tool to read that back into a Color variable? Thank you.

Comment: @jackdh You can use reflection like is suggested in the duplicate question or roll your own implementation with a Map.

Comment: @jackdh try with [Color.getHSBColor()](http://www.tns.lcs.mit.edu/manuals/java-api-old/java.awt.Color.html#HSBtoRGB%28float,%20float,%20float%29) and `Color.RGBtoHSB()`

Comment: @jackdh store red,green and blue in text file and you can use `Color color = new Color(255, 0, 0);`. Please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: So "Red" is not defined a system property. What *is* defined as a system property that `getColor()` can actually return something non-null for?

Answer (score -1):

This is already answered in [How does java.awt.Color.getColor(String colorName) work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772098/how-does-java-awt-color-getcolorstring-colorname-work)

You expect the method to do something else than it does. Maybe you also want to use

```
Color.RED
```

instead.