# Java Color from String "Yellow"

Tags: java, colors, awt

Is there any way we can get color from String (like "White")?

```
Color color;
Field field = Class.forName("java.awt.Color").getField("Yellow");
color = (Color)field.get(null);
```

I tried [Converting a String to Color in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854043/converting-a-string-to-color-in-java) and it throws error .
What "Field" belongs to? What package do I need to import for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because the field that defines yellow is named `YELLOW` or `yellow`

You have an uppercase Y, which cannot be mapped to a Color. Instead, try:

```
Field field = Class.forName("java.awt.Color").getField("yellow");
```

Look at this class for all the fields contained within Color
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html

The code is just using reflection to access one of these fields.

The list of colours however is quite limited, so I don't know how much use this is likely to be for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
.getField("yellow");
```

"yellow" not "Yellow"