# Get a color from the user as a String and use it in a method that accepts enum values?

Tags: java, colors, enums, awt

How to get a color from the user as a `String` and use it in a method that accepts `Color enum` values?

The idea is to get a color that the user chooses and pass the value (or handle the situation any other way) to a method  `element.setBackground(java.awt.Color)`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting a String to Color in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854043/converting-a-string-to-color-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

I would create a `Map<String, Color>` and populate it with what `String` color names map to which `Color` objects.  You can use [`java.awt.Color`'s own `static` `Color` constants](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#field_summary), e.g. `colorMap.put("BLACK", Color.BLACK);`, or you can insert your own mappings.  Then you can take the user input and perform a lookup with `get` to get the proper `Color` object needed.

Answer (score 2):

This example uses the contents of a textField to set the color of the frame when a button is pressed

```
        Field field = null;
        try {
            field = Color.class.getField(textField.getText().toString());
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        Color color = null;
        try {
            color = (Color)field.get(null);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(color);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're able to get the numeric value of the selected color and parse it into a `String` then you can call [Color.decode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#decode%28java.lang.String%29) method.

For instance white color:

```
element.setBackground(Color.decode("077777777")); // octal format
element.setBackground(Color.decode("0xFFFFFF")); // hexa format
element.setBackground(Color.decode("16777215")); // decimal format
```

From javadoc:

> ```
> public static Color decode(String nm)
>                     throws NumberFormatException
> ```
>
> Converts a String to an integer and returns the specified opaque
>   Color. This method handles string formats that are used to represent
>   octal and hexadecimal numbers.
>
> Parameters:
>       `nm` - a String that represents an opaque color as a 24-bit integer
>
> Returns:
>       the new Color object.

Comment: Sorry, but this is  user unfriendly solution. Only natural language inputs should be used.

Comment: No problem but consider add this in your questions as this is very relevant to your requirements. @MindaugasBernatavičius