# Why is it not possible to construct arguments to methods using Strings?

Tags: java, methods, casting

My idea was to use casting to get a StringBuilder object to pass a valid argument to a method. Like this:

```
public TTTButton(String color) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("Color."+ color.toString().toUpperCase());
    this.setBackground((Color)(Object)sb);// Runtime Exception: java.lang.StringBuilder cannot be cast to java.awt.Color
```

Please share your thoughts on why such things are impossible (or maybe they are possible)?

Comment: Because a cast is not the same thing as an [`Eval` function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143343/is-there-a-java-equivalent-of-the-python-eval-function).

Comment: You can't cast it, because a `String` is not a `Color`.  You can perform a lookup, [as in my answer to your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21103630/java-how-to-get-a-color-value-from-the-user-as-a-string-and-use-it-in-a-method/21103675#21103675).

Comment: A StringBuilder is not a Color. Casting only works if they actually are the right type.

Comment: Fyi, `sb.append("a" + b)` does `sb.append(new StringBuilder("a").append(b).toString())` under the hood so your explicit `StringBuilder` is redundant.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, and if string arguments were automatically evaled as in the example, then `System.out.println("new java.lang.String(\"foo\")");` would be ambiguous.

Comment: Is this question related to this other one? [JAVA: How to get a color value from the user as a String and use it in a method that accepts java.awt.Color enum values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21103630/java-how-to-get-a-color-value-from-the-user-as-a-string-and-use-it-in-a-method/21103930#21103930)

Comment: Yes, I know that "A StringBuilder is not a Color". The form of an answer I was hoping for was "because in situation X it would be ambiguous" or "it would be unsafe in situation X" 

@Mike Samuel: thaks for `System.out.println("new java.lang.String(\"foo\")");`

@dix19: no, its a general question spawned by the situation that also spawned the previous question. It could have been illustrated by another example.

Answer (score 1):

`String` or `StringBuilder` is not `Color` type so you can't use casting here. Maybe try to use `Color.getColor(colorName)` where `colorName` is `String`.

Comment: Note - where it is a `String`, not a `StringBuilder`...

Comment: As people explained before, you just cannot cast from String to Color because the interpreter won't know how to do such a conversion. For the sake of curiosity, a way to do what you want is like this

    import java.awt.Color;
    import bsh.EvalError;
    import bsh.Interpreter;
    
    public class ColorEval {
    
     public static void main(String[] args) throws EvalError {
      Interpreter bsh = new Interpreter();
      bsh.eval("java.awt.Color c = java.awt.Color.BLACK");
      Color black = (Color)bsh.eval("c");
      System.out.println(black.equals(Color.BLACK));
     }
    }

Comment: `public TTTButton(String color) throws EvalError {Color passedColor = (Color)bsh.eval("Color."+ color.toString().toUpperCase()); 
  this.setBackground(passedColor);`



Works fantastically! I think it allows to construct any method, argument or anything from string. 

Thanks!