# How can I use a string as a variable?

Tags: java, string, variables, colors

Here's the situation: I have a program that needs to dynamically assign color using the statement

```
mb.setForeground(Color.????);
```

where ???? is normally RED or GREEN or what have you.  But, since I do not know until runtime what is going to go into that value, I need to pass that information using a string:

```
String fColorTxt = "????";
```

So, the value that fColorTxt is assigned to is the value I want to end up after Color.

I have now done the following, but I have no idea if it's going to work...

```
public enum ColorChoice {
    BLACK   (  0,   0,   0),
    BLUE    (  0,   0, 255), LIGHT_BLUE    (  0, 128, 255), DARK_BLUE    (  0,   0, 128),
    BROWN   (160,  96,   0), LIGHT_BROWN   (208, 144,   0), DARK_BROWN   ( 96,  32,   0),
    CYAN    (  0, 255, 255), LIGHT_CYAN    (176, 255, 255), DARK_CYAN    (  0, 139, 139),
    GRAY    (128, 128, 128), LIGHT_GRAY    (211, 211, 211), DARK_GRAY    ( 64,  64,  64),
    GREY    (128, 128, 128), LIGHT_GREY    (211, 211, 211), DARK_GREY    ( 64,  64,  64),
    GREEN   (  0, 255,   0), LIGHT_GREEN   (128, 255, 128), DARK_GREEN   (  0, 128,   0),
    MAGENTA (255,   0, 255), LIGHT_MAGENTA (255, 144, 255), DARK_MAGENTA (144,   0, 144),
    MINT    ( 96, 221,  96), LIGHT_MINT    (208, 238, 208), DARK_MINT    ( 16, 187,  16),
    ORANGE  (255, 128,   0), LIGHT_ORANGE  (255, 176,  48), DARK_ORANGE  (192,  64,   0),
    PINK    (255, 192, 203), LIGHT_PINK    (255, 128, 255), DARK_PINK    (231,  84, 128),
    YELLOW  (255, 255,   0), LIGHT_YELLOW  (255, 255, 128), DARK_YELLOW  (160, 160,   0),
    WHITE   (255, 255, 255);

    private int iRed;
    private int iGreen;
    private int iBlue;

    ColorChoice(int iRed, int iGreen, int iBlue) {
        this.iRed   = iRed;
        this.iGreen = iGreen;
        this.iBlue  = iBlue;
    }

}
```

I guess I need to figure out how to do a few things.  I ultimately would love to be able to just call a function like so:

```
 sColor = myFunction(fColorTxt);
 mb.setForeground(sColor);
 sColor = myFunction(bColorTxt);
 mb.setBackground(sColor);
```

where bColorTxt and fColorTxt are dynamically set at runtime using variables, and sColor is of the Color type.

(The below may still be true, but obviously I've written the names into my enum so it is no longer necessary):

(Only in some cases.  I want to use 8 of java's original predefined colors, and then I defined another 20 or so of my own that I will have to figure out how to handle putting them in; e.g.:

```
Color myDarkYellow   = new Color (160, 160,   0);
```

and then

```
if (fColorTxt == "DARK_YELLOW") { fColor = myDarkYellow; }
mb.setForeground(fColor);
```

Does that look right or is there a better way to handle that?)

Comment: Please tag the appropriate language in use here. At first I thought JavaScript, but then you say Java, but you have tagged nothing.

Comment: sorry, done.  thanks.

Comment: Perhaps this question will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854043/converting-a-string-to-color-in-java

Comment: Oooh, ok, that seems like it should help... 

So, let's say I do the following:

Comment: Changed the question a bit... sorry and thank you (I am REALLY a newbie at Java... have no idea how it works, really.  Trying!)

Comment: OK so problem with reflection... I'm reading up on it and I see it can really slow down the program.  This is a program that needs to be able to respond in milliseconds every time it's called, and will get called millions of times per day :)  so... that won't work :(

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use Enum for avoid the 28 else if

Comment: Oooh, that'll help a ton.  Thanks!