# Convert String to java.awt.Color

Tags: java, string, colors

I'm trying to convert a `String` object to a `java.awt.Color` object.

I am scanning the input color from an user. The user enters a color and the color is saved in a `String`. I want to put that color into an `ArrayList` of colors from the `String`. How do I do that?

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("\nEnter your color\n" + 
                       "BLUE, BLACK, ORANGE, WHITE, YELLOW, RED, GREEN, PINK:");

String str = sc.next();
str = str.toUpperCase();

private ArrayList<Color> colorArray= new ArrayList<Color>();

// Here I want to put the colors (string str) in the colorArray arraylist.
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Thanks for all the down-votes. But maybe an explanation would be a nice gesture as well.

Comment: You achieve it by first determining the logical steps needed, and then proceeding to convert it to code. When you do not how to do a specific step, you research (primarily by searching with the search engine of your choice), and finally ask a question here if you cannot find the answer.

Comment: But are you using [java.awt.Color](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html) or a custom Color class? If so, then show it.

Comment: I'm using java.awt.Color

Comment: Please look into Map<String, Color> and also into enums.

Comment: Since user input (`str`) is only a *single* color, i.e. one word such as `RED`, what does *"I want to put the **colors** (string str) in the colorArray arraylist"* even mean? What do you expect `colorArray` to contain? And why did you name it "array" when it's a `List`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a String to Color in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854043/converting-a-string-to-color-in-java)

Answer (score 4):

How about doing it through reflection?

```
 Color color = (Color)Color.class.getField(str).get(null);
 colorArray.add(color);
```

You might want to do some exception handling in case the user enters a color that is not a field in the `Color` class.

However, note that this technique will work only for certain basic colors for which the class `java.awt.Color` provide static instance members. E.g. the [class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html) currently provides the following static instance members only:

- black
- blue
- cyan
- darkGray or DARK_GRAY
- lightGray or LIGHT_GRAY
- gray
- green
- magenta
- orange
- pink
- red
- white
- yellow

For other colors like turquoise, you will have to build the `Color` object using an appropriate RGB combination.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of how you could do it with a bit of Java 9:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("\nEnter your color\n" +
            "BLUE, BLACK, ORANGE, WHITE, YELLOW, RED, GREEN, PINK:");

    List<Color> colorArray= new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, Color> colorMap = Map.ofEntries(entry("BLUE", Color.BLUE),
            entry( "BLACK", Color.BLACK),
            entry( "ORANGE", Color.ORANGE)); // TODO: add more colours
    while(sc.hasNext()) {
        String next = sc.next();
        Color c = colorMap.get(next);
        if(c == null) {
            if("END".equals(next)) {
                break;
            }
            System.err.printf("Sorry, could not find %s%n", next);
        }
        else {
            colorArray.add(c);
            System.out.printf("Added %s%n", c);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(colorArray);
}
```

This is the output of a sample run:

```
Enter your color
BLUE, BLACK, ORANGE, WHITE, YELLOW, RED, GREEN, PINK:
> BLUE
Added java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=255]
> BLACK
Added java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=0]
> ORANGE
Added java.awt.Color[r=255,g=200,b=0]
> END
[java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=255], java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=0], java.awt.Color[r=255,g=200,b=0]]
```

Here is another version based on @VHS ideas using reflection:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("\nEnter your color\n" +
            "BLUE, BLACK, ORANGE, WHITE, YELLOW, RED, GREEN, PINK:");
    List<Color> colorArray= new ArrayList<>();
    Class<Color> colorClass = Color.class;
    while(sc.hasNext()) {
        String next = sc.next();
        try {
            Color c = colorClass.cast(colorClass.getField(next.toLowerCase()).get(null));
            colorArray.add(c);
            System.out.printf("Added %s%n", c);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            if("END".equals(next)) {
                break;
            }
            System.err.printf("Sorry, could not find %s%n", next);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(colorArray);
}
```

Ideally you would combine both ideas (use a map and reflection), so that you support the declared colours + non declared colours in java.awt.Color.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TestProj {

    public static void main (String[] args)throws IOException {
        List<Color> colorArray= new ArrayList<Color>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("\nEnter your color\n" + 
                               "BLUE, BLACK, ORANGE, WHITE, YELLOW, RED, GREEN, PINK:");

        while(sc.hasNext()){
            String str = sc.next();
            str = str.toUpperCase();
            colorArray.add(new Color(str));
        }
        System.out.println("Array size: " + colorArray.size());
    }

    static class Color {
        private String color;

        public Color(String color){
            setColor(color);
        }

        public String getColor() {
            return color;
        }

        public void setColor(String color) {
            this.color = color;
            System.out.println(color);
        }



    }

}
```

My output is (Ctrl-Z to terminate loop):
Enter your color
BLUE, BLACK, ORANGE, WHITE, YELLOW, RED, GREEN, PINK:

BLUE BLACK ORANGE

BLUE

BLACK

ORANGE

Array size: 3