# How to get the hexadecimal format from color names in Java?

Tags: java, java-8

I have got color names such as White, Red, Blue, etc., and I'm trying to get its corresponding hexadecimal representation. For example, if I pass an argument such as `White` it should return `#FFFFFF`.

Although it seems simple, there's no straight solution in Java. Following is the code I have tried.

```
private String getHexaColor (String basicColor /* White */) {
    java.awt.Color color;
    try {
        java.lang.reflect.Field field = Class.forName("java.awt.Color").getField(basicColor.toLowerCase());
        color = (Color) field.get(null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        color = null; 
    }

    return (color != null) ? String.format("%06x#", color.getRGB() & 0x00FFFFFF).toUpperCase() : ""; //return #FFFFFF
}
```

Above code is working fine, but I'm looking for a clean and elegant solution if at all available at least in the latest version of Java.

Comment: This looks like a question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I googled some.  The best I could find is a S.O. question with the answer being to do just this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854043/converting-a-string-to-color-in-java - there some other options there involving 3rd party solutions. - I would think there would be a list of colors with hex values online somewhere that you could grab and use.

Comment: What is your universe of possible color names?

Comment: I found a really exhaustive list of colors and hex values.  If it were me, I'd probably wrap some code around that. - https://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.html

Answer (score 2):

You should use the format string `"#%06X"` rather than `"%06x#"`. First, it places the `#` character at the position you actually want, second, it generates an upper case hexadecimal string, removing the need to call `toUpperCase()` on the result.

But how much does your reflective operation save, compared to an explicit map of values? When I run over all fields of `Color`, e.g. via

```
final int constant = Modifier.STATIC | Modifier.FINAL;
Map<String,Integer> m = new HashMap<>();
for(Field f: Color.class.getFields()) try {
    if((f.getModifiers() & constant) == constant && f.getType() == Color.class)
        m.put(f.getName().toLowerCase().replace('_', ' '),
            ((Color)f.get(null)).getRGB() & 0x00FFFFFF);
} catch(ReflectiveOperationException ex) {
    throw new AssertionError(ex);
}
m.forEach((name,rgb) -> System.out.printf("map.put(\"%s\", \"#%06X\");%n", name, rgb));
```

I get

```
map.put("magenta", "#FF00FF");
map.put("pink", "#FFAFAF");
map.put("green", "#00FF00");
map.put("black", "#000000");
map.put("yellow", "#FFFF00");
map.put("cyan", "#00FFFF");
map.put("dark gray", "#404040");
map.put("red", "#FF0000");
map.put("orange", "#FFC800");
map.put("gray", "#808080");
map.put("white", "#FFFFFF");
map.put("blue", "#0000FF");
map.put("darkgray", "#404040");
map.put("light gray", "#C0C0C0");
map.put("lightgray", "#C0C0C0");
```

which is not that big. So, when I copy that output into a new code like

```
static final Map<String,String> COLOR_CODES;
static {
    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("magenta", "#FF00FF");
    map.put("pink", "#FFAFAF");
    map.put("green", "#00FF00");
    map.put("black", "#000000");
    map.put("yellow", "#FFFF00");
    map.put("cyan", "#00FFFF");
    map.put("dark gray", "#404040");
    map.put("red", "#FF0000");
    map.put("orange", "#FFC800");
    map.put("gray", "#808080");
    map.put("white", "#FFFFFF");
    map.put("blue", "#0000FF");
    map.put("darkgray", "#404040");
    map.put("light gray", "#C0C0C0");
    map.put("lightgray", "#C0C0C0");
    COLOR_CODES = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
}
static String getHexaColor(String colorName) {
    return COLOR_CODES.getOrDefault(colorName.toLowerCase(), "");
}
```

the result is simple and reflection free. Maintenance would be independent of the reflective code that produced this version, as it is simpler to add a new constant to the map than to add a new constant to the `java.awt.Color` class (to re-run the reflective code).

The only alternative with more flexibility would be to use a [properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) file, which allows to update the map without recompiling the application. It’s easy to adapt the code above to generate a properties file instead, but on the other hand, there are enough ready-to-use files on the internet with even more colors. E.g., you can copy the VGA based web colors directly from [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/SPSD-html32-20180315/#colors), whereas [this extended list](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-3/#svg-color) would require an advanced search-and-replace to be brought into the properties format.

Answer (score 0):

Using Color from OpenFX, one disposes over a method for all web colors.

```
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
Color color = Color.web("skyblue");
```

Result:

```
0x87cdebff
```

These exist also as constant fields, so one might use autocompletion. But I like the autocompletion in a CSS/HTML editor.

---

This is a separate dependency, library. But as of java 9 a modular infrastructure is to be expected, and OpenFX, formerly JavaFX, is unproblematic.